# Regular expression to transform SQL format to java format

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying with no chance to transform sql attributes to java format.
Let's have an example: I want to change: "p_start_date" to "pStartSate".

I've tried to use

```
String var = "p_start_date";
var.replaceAll("(_[a-z])\1", "([A-Z])\1");
```

and also

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-z0-9]+_)*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(var);


    if (matcher.find()) {
        // Get all groups for this match
        //System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
        for (int i=0; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            String groupStr = matcher.group(i);
            System.out.println(groupStr);
        }
    }
```

But both doesn't work

Comment: why do you need it ? if you want to make java objects out of tables you could use an ORM framework.

Comment: I'm using named queries in my JEE project and it returns a DTO. That's why I'm using this conventionality

Comment: @Simeon do you have any proposal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String var = "p_start_date";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_([a-z])");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(var);

StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer();
while(matcher.find()) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, matcher.group(1).toUpperCase());
}
matcher.appendTail(sb);

System.out.println(sb);
```

output: **pStartDate**

Comment: Please don't use a StringBuffer when you can use a StringBuilder.